# Solving 2nd order differential equation in the for loop

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve the [Duffing equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duffing_equation), which is a second-order differential equation. I am able to get the steady-state plot, but I do not know how to get maximum value from the last few points and the vary the frequency to get a plot of w vs y. I have tried the following code to just startup

```
ClearAll[m, k, F, w, k3, e, g]
m = 1;
k = 1;
F = 0.01;
w = 1;
k3 = 10^-4;
e = 10^-5;
g = 0.001;
center = 1;
range = .05;
start = center - range/2;
stop = center + range/2;
pts = 100;
step = (stop - start)/pts;
eqn = {m*y''[x] + m*g*y'[x] + k*y[x] + k3*y[x]^3 + e*y[x]^2*y'[x] - 
     F*Cos[w*x] == 0, y[0] == 0, y'[0] == 0};
c = Range[start, stop, step];
s = Table[NDSolve[eqn, y, {x, 0, 50}], {w, Length@c}];
Plot[s, {t, 0, 60}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", ImageSize -> Large]
```

Comment: Do you know about [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)? I think it does what you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the comment of Roman (using [`ParametricNDSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolve.html)) is definitely a valid point and most likely the best solution for this kind of application. The manual approach suggested by OP is not impossible. The code presented by OP has several typos in the line defining `s`, which I fixed in the version below

```
ClearAll[m,k,F,w,k3,e,g]
m=1;
k=1;
F=0.01;
k3=10^-4;
e=10^-5;
g=0.001;
center=1;
range=.05;
start=center-range/2;
stop=center+range/2;
pts=100;
step=(stop-start)/pts;
eqn={m*y''[x]+m*g*y'[x]+k*y[x]+k3*y[x]^3+e*y[x]^2*y'[x]-F*Cos[w*x]==0,y[0]==0,y'[0]==0};
c=Range[start,stop,step];
s=Table[NDSolveValue[eqn,y,{x,0,50}][t],{w,c}];
p1=Plot[s,{t,0,50},ImageSize->Large,PlotRange->All,FrameLabel->{"x","y[x]"},GridLines->Automatic];

wData=MapThread[{#1,NMaximize[{#2,0<=t<=50},t]}&,{c,s}];
Transpose[{wData[[All,1]],wData[[All,2,1]]}];
p2=ListLinePlot[%,Frame->True,FrameLabel->{"w","Subscript[y, max]"},GridLines->Automatic,ImageSize->Large];
SortBy[%%,-#[[2]]&]//First
Grid[{{p1,p2}}]
```

which results in (Warning: the computation took around 40 seconds of wall time on my laptop)

> [image: Output]

where the maximum amplitude of $\sim 0.2259$ is reached for $w=0.9945$. The same could be realized using `ParametricNDSolve` in the code above:

```
...
eqn={m*y''[x]+m*g*y'[x]+k*y[x]+k3*y[x]^3+e*y[x]^2*y'[x]-F*Cos[w*x]==0,y[0]==0,y'[0]==0};
c=Range[start,stop,step];
sol=ParametricNDSolveValue[eqn,y,{x,0,50},w]
s=Table[sol[w][t],{w,c}];
...
```

which took again roughly 40 seconds to evaluate (I have not benchmarked this using multiple runs). Which makes sense since `ParametricNDSolveValue` and its output `ParametricFunction` is basically a fancy wrapper for `NDSolve` (with maybe some additional functionalities).

Comment: @Nova, please correct me if I am wrong. what is the role of t in this line s=Table[NDSolveValue[eqn,y,{x,0,50}][t],{w,c}];

Comment: @ShelenderKumar The line computes the solutions for the given set of  `w`: stored in `c` up to `t=50`. One can only reliably plot/evaluated the computed solutions between `t=0` and `t=50`. If one wants to evolve to later times one would need to change `{x,0,50}` in `NDSolveValue` to something like `{x,0,tmax}`.

Comment: I want to change the initial condition in such a way that every time a new value of c is taken initial condition changes to y(0)=y(end) and y'(0)=y'(end);.